# How to add single quotes to a string in javascriipt which is going to be execute as mysql insertion command in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

1. pass the string to addSingleQuotes function and which returns an string
2. For example your string is 'val1,val2,val3' and the out come from this function is 'val1','val2','val3'
3. The return string is very help for insertion command string for MYSQL

My code is here:

```
    var addSingleQuotes = function (str) {

        var tempArr = str.split(",");
        var retStr = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < tempArr.length; i++) {

            retStr = retStr+"'" + tempArr[i] + "',";
        }
        return retStr.substr(0, retStr.length-1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the example provided you can do something like this:

Given the input `str = "'val1,val2,val3'";`

```
function addSingleQuotes(str) {
  return str
    .split(',')
    .map(function (word) {
      return "'" + word.replace(/[']/g, '') + "'"; 
    })
    .join(',');
}
```